# Error: The method 'clampDouble' isn't defined for the class '_DropdownMenuPainter'

Tags: flutter

I'm using https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_button2/versions/1.8.0/

I'm using exapmle, error this:

**Error: The method 'clampDouble' isn't defined for the class '_DropdownMenuItemButtonState'.**

**Error: The method 'clampDouble' isn't defined for the class '_DropdownMenuPainter'.**

*Flutter 3.0.5*

Answer (score 0):

clampDouble is a function from foundation class

you can try:
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
OR
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' show clampDouble;

but this clampDouble issue is because of flutter and fvm flutter version issue.
In my case I did *pub get* with fvm flutter but on building the app I ran the command of *flutter build apk*.
Because the project's dependencies was with fvm flutter, it auto rerun the command flutter pub get* by itself and caused the clampDouble issue.

---

**do 'fvm flutter pub get'**
**then**
**'fvm flutter build apk'**

**^ this will fixed the error**